# Import tensorflow in Anaconda2: undefined symbol

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, jupyter

This morning I am trying to install tensorflow on Anaconda3 (python version 3.5 & Ubuntu 16.04). I installed tensorflow with `conda install tensorflow`. However, it does not work well when importing it python/jupyter notebook.

```
Python 3.5.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Aug 26 2018, 21:41:56) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/work/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/work/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/home/work/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "/home/work/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/protobuf/descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: /home/work/.conda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK6google8protobuf10TextFormat17FieldValuePrinter9PrintBoolEb
>>>
```

Have anyone encountered this before? I notice there are similar cases but the solution might not work with Anaconda3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Install tensoflow pypi-package with pip

I had exactly the same error. The tensorflow version 1.0.0 was required for my application. There seems to be a difference between the conda-package and pypi-package of tensorflow. So uninstall the conda-package of tensorflow in `<YOUR_CONDA_ENV>`ironement and pip-install the pipy-package again:

```sh
# uninstall current tensorflow conda-package 
$ sudo conda uninstall --name <YOUR_CONDA_ENV> tensorflow
# install the pypi-package of tensorflow
$ sudo <YOUR_CONDA_ENV_PATH>/bin/pip install tensorflow==<REQUIRED_VERSION>
```

In your case `<YOUR_CONDA_ENV>=tensorflow` and the path to your conda environment location is `<YOUR_CONDA_ENV_PATH>=/home/work/.conda/envs/tensorflow`.

Make sure you use the `pip install` of your conda environment (`<YOUR_CONDA_ENV_PATH>/bin/pip`) and not the general pip (`/bin/pip`). If you haven't installed pip in your environment yet, just:

```sh
$ sudo conda install --name <YOUR_CONDA_ENV> pip
```